# Desperate HELP - Ubuntu 18.04 - usb 3.0 4TB never standby

Tags: usb

<< First of all sorry for grammatical errors, I'm using a translator >>

I searched with Google but I find no answer and here we are!
I really need a guru because I swear I don't come to the fore...

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and I have these two external USB hard drives 3 that I can never get to spindown.

```
Vendor:               Seagate
Product:              M3 Portable
Revision:             9300
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        4.000.787.029.504 bytes [4,00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
Logical Unit id:      0x5000000000000001
Serial number:        NM13R59H
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Tue Jun 12 20:00:34 2018 CEST
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Disabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported


Vendor:               Seagate
Product:              Expansion
Revision:             9300
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        4.000.787.029.504 bytes [4,00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
Logical Unit id:      0x5000000000000001
Serial number:        NZ0E3577
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Tue Jun 12 20:01:15 2018 CEST
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Disabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported
```

I've tried with : sudo hdparm -S 100 /dev/sdc1

```
/dev/sdc1:
 setting standby to 100 (8 minutes + 20 seconds)
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

But it doesn't work..

Another thing, why an usb3 seen as SCSI? Look here:

```
dmesg | grep scsi
[    1.944067] scsi host0: ahci
[    1.955138] scsi host1: ahci
[    2.442233] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Samsung SSD 850  2B6Q PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.442941] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    2.626124] scsi host2: uas
[    2.626646] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  M3 Portable      9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    2.627269] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    2.628374] scsi host3: uas
[    2.628818] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    2.629341] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
```

Thank you really heartily to anyone who wants to help me!